# Proving a sequence is Null, Help!

Tags: sequences-and-series, formal-proofs

I have this question:
Use the deﬁnition of a null sequence to prove that the sequence $\{a_n\}$
given by
$a_n = \dfrac{2}{2n^2 -3}, n = 1, 2, \dots ,$
is null.
So I know that we want to show for $\epsilon >0 $there is an integer $N$ that $\dfrac{2}{2n^2 -3}<\epsilon.$ But how do I do this?

Comment: What is a "null sequence"?

Comment: Same homework? We had the same question the 12th, apparently now homework is due. Anyway your text is not understandable at the end. And you don't show any own work here.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* $2n^2 - 3 > n^2 > n, \forall n \geq 2 \Rightarrow \dfrac{2}{2n^2-3} < \dfrac{2}{n}, \forall n \geq 2.$

Comment: @DanZimm: I said $\forall n \geq 2.$ It's certainly true for $n=2.$ Suppose it's true for $n=r.$ Now $2(r+1)^2 - 3 = 2r^2 -3 +4r+2 > r^2+2r+1=(r+1)^2.$ Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: oops, didn't realize that was snuck in there, apologies!